# How to produce equally sized bins with pandas cut?

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas own documentation on the `cut` method, it says that it produces equally sized bins. However, in the example they provide, it clearly doesn't:

```
>>>pd.cut(np.array([1, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3]), 3)

[(0.994, 3.0], (5.0, 7.0], (3.0, 5.0], (3.0, 5.0], (5.0, 7.0], ...
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(0.994, 3.0] < (3.0, 5.0] ...
```

The first interval is larger than all the others, why is that?

Edit: even if the smallest number (1) in the array is made more than 1 (e.g. 1.001), it still produces bins of unequal width:

```
In [291]: pd.cut(np.array([1.001, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3]), 3)    
Out[291]: 
[(0.995, 3.001], (5.0, 7.0], (3.001, 5.0], (3.001, 5.0], (5.0, 7.0], (0.995, 3.001]]
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(0.995, 3.001] < (3.001, 5.0] < (5.0, 7.0]]
```

Comment: Hmm not sure why I'm being downvoted

Answer (score 1):

[For the kind of performance you get](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py#L32-L268), I can live with this amount of fractional inaccuracy. However, if you know your data and want to get as close to evenly spaced bins as possible, use `linspace` for the bin spec (similar to [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py#L235)):

```
arr = np.array([1, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3])
pd.cut(arr, np.linspace(arr.min(), arr.max(), 3+1), include_lowest=True) 
# [(0.999, 3.0], (5.0, 7.0], (3.0, 5.0], (3.0, 5.0], (5.0, 7.0], (0.999, 3.0]]
# Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(0.999, 3.0] < (3.0, 5.0] < (5.0, 7.0]]
```

Comment: So it's about efficiency/speed?

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh Isn't it?

Comment: I don't think so, because in the documentation it says  ```The range of x is extended by .1% on each side to include the minimum and maximum values of x.``` But I don't understand why it doesn't do it to the maximum (i.e. the other side).

Comment: example: ```pd.cut(np.array([1, 7.01, 5, 4, 6, 3]), 3)      
Out[32]: 
[(0.994, 3.003], (5.007, 7.01], (3.003, 5.007], (3.003, 5.007], (5.007, 7.01], (0.994, 3.003]]
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(0.994, 3.003] < (3.003, 5.007] < (5.007, 7.01]]```